# You don't seem to have a generator with the name hubot installed

Tags: hubot, yo

I tried to use hubot. And I run following commands in OSX 10.9.

> sudo npm install -g hubot yo generator-hubot
>   yo hubot

But, I couldn't create new project. and I get following error code

> Error hubot
>
> You don't seem to have a generator with the name hubot installed.
>   You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm >install [name].
>   To see the 2 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.

In my environment,
npm is v2.1.14.
node.js is v0.10.26
path of npm is /usr/local/bin/npm
path of node is /usr/local/bin/node

I tried `yo doctor`,I got `[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks all right!`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly your problem is that you installed the generators as root, but are attempting to scaffold as your user -- try re-running without sudo:

```
npm install -g hubot
```

Answer (score 0):

- Install **generator-hubot** library after installing yeomen `npm install -g yo`

```
npm install generator-hubot
```

- Run hubot generator

```
yo hubot
```